# What is the proper way to run SQLite code off the UI thread when there are so many CRUD methods?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, crud

When I write database code in my app, I have a lot of CRUD functions, most of which involve some combination of storing things in `ContentValues` or using `Cursors` or performing operations on the database object via `SQLiteOpenHelper` and so on and so on.

For each object in my app, this means writing at least 4 -- and usually more -- methods. It's tedious, and probably not as sophisticated as the ORMs I don't understand how to use properly, and I worry it violates DRY principle, but I have more control over things.

However, I also know that you're not supposed to run SQL code off the UI thread. Does this mean I have to double the number of methods I have, since I need one method to create the new thread/runnable and then from there call the corresponding CRUD function?

Comment: There are a number of things you can do - I've been preferring using RXJava for background stuff recently - if you're already familiar with RX, you can check out https://github.com/square/sqlbrite. The recommendations from Google are here (https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) and if you follow it, you will likely avoid a lot of pitfalls, so recommended for those that are new go Android - I just find the `Loader` semantics rather cumbersome. Hope this helps.

Comment: Writing database code just is tedious.  There's no real way around it.  You can use ORMs and the like, but they still end up being tedious and frequently require more data from the db and more requests to the db, since to change anything about an object you now need to fetch the entire thing.  There's not a lot of data to me showing that they actually improve things.  Relational data is not a set of objects, and treating it like one rarely works well from an efficiency or correctness point of view.  As for threading-  if a request is quick its perfectly ok to do it on the UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use a `ContentProvider` together with a `ContentResolver` to manage your database. You can easily take the operations off the main thread using a `AsyncQueryHandler`.

I have also created a small library that helps you with that - [Bender](https://github.com/dalexiev/bender)